# Modifying Large files line by line using perl script

Tags: perl, csv

I am having two huge .csv files one is around 8 GB and other is 3.4 GB file size.  I want only few values from each line inside that .csv files.
Its taking huge time to modify the data and copy it into new file.

Could anyone help in modifying the code.So that the modification will be completed in a reasonable time.

Below is the lines of code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV;

require "$ENV{'SAI_HOME'}/bin/utils/Logging.pl";
require "$ENV{'SAI_HOME'}/bin/utils/Utilities.pl";

my $date1 = `date '+%d-%m-%Y_%H-%M-%Ss'`;
chomp($date1);
our $LOGPATH = "$ENV{'SAI_HOME'}/logs/SP6migrationcsv_$date1.log";
my $status = 0;
log_info("Refer $LOGPATH log file for more information");
my $csv = Text::CSV->new( { binary => 1, eol => $/, sep_char => ',' } );
my $file1 = $ARGV[0] or die "Please provide Subscriber and Subscription CSV files on the command line\n";
my $file2 = $ARGV[1] or die "Please provide Subscriber and Subscription CSV files on the command line\n";
my $subscriberFile   = "";
my $subscriptionFile = "";

if ( ( grep /SUBSCRIBER/i, $file1 ) && ( grep /SUBSCRIPTION/i, $file2 ) ) {
    $subscriberFile   = $file1;
    $subscriptionFile = $file2;
} elsif ( ( grep /SUBSCRIBER/i, $file2 ) && ( grep /SUBSCRIPTION/i, $file1 ) ) {
    $subscriptionFile = $file1;
    $subscriberFile   = $file2;
} else {
    log_error("Invalid CSV files input");
    exit -1;
}
my $SP6DIR = `dirname $0`;
chomp $SP6DIR;
$SP6DIR = "${SP6DIR}/SP6";
`mkdir -p $SP6DIR` or checkExit( $?, "Unable to carete $SP6DIR directory" );
my $newSubscriberFile    = "Subscriber.csv";
my $newSubscriptionFile  = "Subscription.csv";
my $subscriptionimsifile = "$SP6DIR/.IMSI_$newSubscriptionFile";
my $subscriberimsifile   = "$SP6DIR/.IMSI_$newSubscriberFile";
$newSubscriberFile   = "${SP6DIR}/$newSubscriberFile";
$newSubscriptionFile = "${SP6DIR}/$newSubscriptionFile";
`dos2unix $subscriptionFile $subscriberFile 2>/dev/null`
    or checkExit( $?, "Unable to perform dos2unix on input files" );
`cut -d "," -f3 $subscriptionFile > $subscriptionimsifile`
    or checkExit( $?, "Failed to get IMSI details from $subscriptionFile" );
`cut -d "," -f1 $subscriberFile > $subscriberimsifile`
    or checkExit( $?, "Failed to get IMSI details from $subscriberFile" );
my $isSubscriptionHeaderPresesnt = "false";
my $isSubscriberHeaderPresesnt   = "false";
$status = system("head -1 $subscriptionimsifile | grep 'IMSI' >>/dev/null");

if ( $status == 0 ) {
    $isSubscriptionHeaderPresesnt = "true";
}
$status = system("head -1 $subscriberimsifile | grep 'IMSI' >>/dev/null");
if ( $status == 0 ) {
    $isSubscriberHeaderPresesnt = "true";
}
open( my $subscriptionData, '<:encoding(utf8)', $subscriptionFile )
    or die "Could not open '$subscriptionFile' $!\n";
open( NEWSUBSCRIBERDATA,   "> $newSubscriberFile" )   or die "Could not open '$newSubscriberFile' $!\n";
open( NEWSUBSCRIPTIONDATA, "> $newSubscriptionFile" ) or die "Could not open '$newSubscriptionFile' $!\n";
if ( "$isSubscriptionHeaderPresesnt" eq "true" ) {
    my $subscriptionHeader = <$subscriptionData>;
    if ( $csv->parse($subscriptionHeader) ) {
        my @subscriptionHeaderFields = $csv->fields();
        print NEWSUBSCRIPTIONDATA "\"$subscriptionHeaderFields[0]\",\"$subscriptionHeaderFields[2]\",\"$subscriptionHeaderFields[4]\",\"$subscriptionHeaderFields[5]\",\"$subscriptionHeaderFields[6]\",\"$subscriptionHeaderFields[8]\",\"$subscriptionHeaderFields[13]\",\"$subscriptionHeaderFields[14]\",\"$subscriptionHeaderFields[15]\",\"$subscriptionHeaderFields[16]\",\"$subscriptionHeaderFields[17]\",\"$subscriptionHeaderFields[18]\",\"$subscriptionHeaderFields[25]\",\"$subscriptionHeaderFields[26]\",\"$subscriptionHeaderFields[27]\"\n";
        print NEWSUBSCRIBERDATA "\"IMSI\",\"IMEI\",\"MSISDN\",\"$subscriptionHeaderFields[21]\",\"$subscriptionHeaderFields[22]\",\"$subscriptionHeaderFields[12]\",\"$subscriptionHeaderFields[9]\",\"$subscriptionHeaderFields[1]\",\"$subscriptionHeaderFields[0]\"\n";
    } else {
        log_error("Line could not be parsed: $subscriptionHeader\n");
        exit 1;
    }
} else {
    log_only("No header info in subscription file");
}

if ( "$isSubscriptionHeaderPresesnt" eq "false" && "$isSubscriberHeaderPresesnt" eq "true" ) {
    print NEWSUBSCRIBERDATA "\"IMSI\",\"IMEI\",\"MSISDN\",\"CUSTOMER_SEGMENTATION\",\"CUST_SUBCATEGORY\",\"SUBS_TYPE\",\"SUBSCRIPTION_PLAN\",\"CONTRACT_IDREF\",\"SUBSCRIPTION_IDREF\"\n";
} else {
    log_only("No header info in subscriber file");
}
my $subscriberHeader   = "";
my @subscriptionFields = {};
my @subscriberFields   = {};

while ( my $eachSubscriptionLine = <$subscriptionData> ) {
    chomp $eachSubscriptionLine;
    if ( $csv->parse($eachSubscriptionLine) ) {
        @subscriptionFields = $csv->fields();
        $status = system("grep \"^[\\\"]*${subscriptionFields[2]}[\\\"]*\\\$\" $subscriberimsifile >> /dev/null");
        if ( $status == 0 ) {
            my $lastMatchedSubscriberdata = `grep  "^[\\\"]*${subscriptionFields[2]}[\\\"]*," $subscriberFile | tail -1`;
            chomp $lastMatchedSubscriberdata;
            if ( $csv->parse($lastMatchedSubscriberdata) ) {
                @subscriberFields = $csv->fields();
                if ( "${subscriberFields[0]}" eq "${subscriptionFields[2]}" ) {
                    #log_only("Updating \"@subscriberFields\" subscriber details from subscription data");
                    print NEWSUBSCRIBERDATA "\"$subscriberFields[0]\",\"$subscriberFields[1]\",\"$subscriptionFields[2]\",\"$subscriptionFields[21]\",\"$subscriptionFields[22]\",\"$subscriptionFields[12]\",\"$subscriptionFields[9]\",\"$subscriptionFields[1]\",\"$subscriptionFields[0]\"\n";
                } else {
                    log_error("Unable to process @subscriberFields record");
                    exit -1;
                }
            } else {
                log_error("Line could not be parsed: $lastMatchedSubscriberdata\n");
                exit 1;
            }
        } else {
            log_only("Adding new subscriber details from subscription : \"@subscriptionFields\"");
            print NEWSUBSCRIBERDATA "\"$subscriptionFields[2]\",,\"$subscriptionFields[3]\",\"$subscriptionFields[21]\",\"$subscriptionFields[22]\",\"$subscriptionFields[12]\",\"$subscriptionFields[9]\",\"$subscriptionFields[1]\",\"$subscriptionFields[0]\"\n";
        }
        print NEWSUBSCRIPTIONDATA "\"$subscriptionFields[0]\",\"$subscriptionFields[2]\",\"$subscriptionFields[4]\",\"$subscriptionFields[5]\",\"$subscriptionFields[6]\",\"$subscriptionFields[8]\",\"$subscriptionFields[13]\",\"$subscriptionFields[14]\",\"$subscriptionFields[15]\",\"$subscriptionFields[16]\",\"$subscriptionFields[17]\",\"$subscriptionFields[18]\",\"$subscriptionFields[25]\",\"$subscriptionFields[26]\",\"$subscriptionFields[27]\"\n";
    } else {
        log_error("Line could not be parsed: $eachSubscriptionLine\n");
        exit 1;
    }
}
close(NEWSUBSCRIPTIONDATA);
open( my $subscriberData, '<:encoding(utf8)', $subscriberFile ) || die "Could not open '$subscriberFile' $!\n";
if ( "$isSubscriberHeaderPresesnt" eq "true" ) {
    $subscriberHeader = <$subscriberData>;
}
while ( my $eachSubscriberLine = <$subscriberData> ) {
    chomp $eachSubscriberLine;
    if ( $csv->parse($eachSubscriberLine) ) {
        @subscriberFields = $csv->fields();
        $status = system("grep \"^[\\\"]*${subscriberFields[0]}[\\\"]*\\\$\" $subscriptionimsifile >>/dev/null");
        if ( $status != 0 ) {
            log_only(
                "Adding back subscriber details, because unable to get IMSI details from subscription file : \"@subscriberFields\""
            );
            print NEWSUBSCRIBERDATA "\"$subscriberFields[0]\",\"$subscriberFields[1]\",\"$subscriberFields[2]\",\"$subscriberFields[6]\",,\"$subscriberFields[7]\",,,\n";
        }
    } else {
        log_error("Line could not be parsed: $eachSubscriberLine\n");
        exit 1;
    }
}
close(NEWSUBSCRIBERDATA);
`sed -i -e '1 s|SUBSCRIPTION_ID|SUBSCRIPTION_IDREF|g' -e '1 s|SUBS_CATEGORY|SUBSCRIPTION_PLAN|g'  -e '1 s|SUBS_STATE|SUBS_TYPE|g'  -e '1 s|CUST_CATEGORY|CUSTOMER_SEGMENTATION|g' $newSubscriberFile`
    or checkExit( $?, "Unable to update header info in subscriber fi   le" );
```

Comment: @jm666 that is ok, but then you should not complain regarding performance. If csv is mandatory it could be used just as import/export database format, but not for frequent updates.

Comment: @mpapec thats's fair :)

Comment: Probably only few people will want analyze your long code, where you calling many times external `cut` commands and such. The best you can do, find what part of your code tooks most time, reduce the problem to few line of code and provide some sample input and an sample of the wanted output. Without isn't much possible recommend something more as, _don't call 3 external processes on 8GB file_ and _process the lines in sequence.._ and such common things... And please read [ask].

Comment: Do you understand this line? `$status=system("grep \"^[\\\"]*${subscriberFields[0]}[\\\"]*\\\$\" $subscriptionimsifile >>/dev/null");` ? you calling external shell command for every line of your file, and complaining about it speed?

Comment: One simple thing you can do to track down the slow bit(s) is to add `print` statements at various intervals within your script and watch for pauses between them.

Answer (score 4):

General advice:

- Don't use backticks to parse your input. Perl is perfectly capable of doing this with a `while` loop and `split`.
- Misspelling variable names is going to screw you. Don't. `isSubscriptionHeaderPresesnt`
- mixing your `open` calls - 3 argument with lexicals is generally preferred, but mismatching isn't nice.
- Using the text string "false" in lieu of a boolean is horrible. Don't do it. Someone someday is going to do the equivalent of `print "true" if "false"` and it's going to break.
- The most 'expensive' operation your script will be doing is reading the files. That's almost always true. So find something other than syscalls to `grep` or `sed` require full-rereading of the files you're targeting. Assuming `subscriptionFile` and `subscriberFile`  are your biggies, you're reading them multiple times - you're running a `cut` that reads the whole thing. A `dos2unix` that reads the whole thing.  A `grep` that reads the whole thing. And then you're `open`ing it, and reading the whole thing.
- your last line is a `sed` which will... re-read your output file, entirely, and apply a line by line transform to it.